# How to view weights of a pretrained model after transfer learning?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, vgg-net

I'm following a transfer learning tutorial explained [here](https://www.guru99.com/transfer-learning.html) and saved the weights after training using:

```
torch.save(vgg_based.state_dict(), 'model1.pth')
```

When I try to load the model like this:

```
model = torchvision.models.vgg19()
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('model1.pth'))
model.eval()
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-423f6125f9e6> in <module>
      5 # features.extend([torch.nn.Linear(number_features, len(class_names))])
      6 # model.classifier = torch.nn.Sequential(*features)
----> 7 model.load_state_dict(torch.load('model1.pth'))
      8 model.eval()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in load_state_dict(self, state_dict, strict)
   1222         if len(error_msgs) > 0:
   1223             raise RuntimeError('Error(s) in loading state_dict for {}:\n\t{}'.format(
-> 1224                                self.__class__.__name__, "\n\t".join(error_msgs)))
   1225         return _IncompatibleKeys(missing_keys, unexpected_keys)
   1226 

RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for VGG:
    size mismatch for classifier.6.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([2, 4096]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([1000, 4096]).
    size mismatch for classifier.6.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([2]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([1000])
```

I understand this is because I need to edit the network to reflect the number of outputs so before I load the model I should follow the same procedure during training, therefore loading the model like this:

```
model = torchvision.models.vgg19()
#modify the last layers
number_features = model.classifier[6].in_features
features = list(model.classifier.children())[:-1]  #remove the last layer
features.extend([torch.nn.Linear(number_features, len(class_names))])
model.classifier = torch.nn.Sequential(*features)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('model1.pth'))
model.eval()
```

Is this correct? How can I view the values of the weights and confirm I have loaded the newly trained model correctly?

Answer (score -1):

You have changed the last linear layer, so there will be a shape mismatch when loading the state dictionary on your current model.

- You can either discard this by making it a warning instead of throwing an error by setting the strict argument to False on [`load_state_dict`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.load_state_dict):

  ```
  state = torch.load('model1.pth')
  diff = model.load_state_dict(state, strict=False)
  print(diff)
  ```

  `diff` will give you a list of all the mismatched entries.
- Or by popping the concerning layers out of the dictionary altogether before loading:

  ```
  state = torch.load('model1.pth')
  state.pop('classifier.6.weight')
  state.pop('classifier.6.bias')
  model.load_state_dict(state)
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question is how to see the weight values in the two models. When I run your code I get the same error I posted in my question.

Comment: @user42 Can you post the exact error stack trace when running the first code?